# How to search old versions of web pages, e.g., YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, google-search, cached-webpages

3 days ago, Google changed the HTML of YouTube to not include the words "like 132" "dislike 10" etc. Now the ratings values of videos are encrypted in unsearchable buttons:

```
<img src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif" class="yt-uix-button-icon yt-uix-button-icon-watch-like yt-sprite" alt="I like this"></span><span class="yt-uix-button-content">238,315 </span></button>
```

I had a Google Search hack for YouTube: I would search:

```
"like 100..200" "dislike 0..2" Moog site:youtube.com
```

I *loved* typing that phrase as I found some truly amazing results using it that I could never find using YouTube's awkward "ratings filter".

However, Google has now changed YouTube and purged Google search of all old YouTube pages.

How can I search old versions so I can do my YouTube ratings search hack?

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you want to do. You want to google search based on how many likes/dislikes a video has?

Comment: Yes. I want to still search YouTube sites by rating. For example, i can search Discogs.com for albums with 4.95, it's fun. However, since recently, YouTube has deleted ratings information from all it's search results, so i would like any solution to still do equivalent of google search : "like 100..200" "dislike 0" videotopic site:youtube.com

Comment: When I search that I still see in the description "Likes # Dislikes #" etc., except that Google doesn't search for the exact combination. By the way, what are the 3 dots for?

Comment: At the top of the search page it will say "No results were found ... etc" whereas previously there were 100's of results!  *..* is google range, so *"photo 1880..1930"* in google images will return a range. Before i was getting lots of results of this kind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZPmMqxf3nNI and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gViHMT8wks

Comment: archive.org perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

To search for old versions of webpages you should use a search engine that index archived web pages like https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php.

Example of search query for youtube web pages: [collection:(youtube.com) AND mediatype:(web)](https://archive.org/search.php?query=collection%3A%28youtube.com%29%20AND%20mediatype%3A%28web%29)

Comment: Thanks, i tried that at the time and again now, the result is that i get about 72 pages from YT prior to 2015, so it's as if YT was not recorded on archive.org